# AngularJS и Django REST: как передать объект для редактирования с одной страницы на другую?

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

Задача: выводить на страницу список записей из бд, с возможностью их редактирования и добавления новых. 
Т.е. есть `template`, который при помощи `$http.get` запроса получает набор записей от `Django REST`, со стороны `REST` имеется `TemplateView`, который выводит сам шаблон, и `APIView`, который по запросу возвращает данные.

Редактирование и добавление новой записи происходит следующим образом: открывается модальное окно, в него передаются данные из основной страницы. При нажатии на кнопку Сохранить данные отправляются в `API`, при помощи `$http.post`. Если происходит добавление новой записи - поля формы заполняются по умолчанию, если редактирование - на основе данных редактируемой записи (т.е. объекта).

Проблема: при создании аналогичной страницы для другого набора данных набор полей слишком большой для модального окна. Пришла, как вариант, идея при редактировании и добавлении переходить на отдельную страницу с формой. Но возник вопрос - как ее заполнить? По идее достаточно передать в этот контроллер `id` редактируемой записи, тогда можно запросить у `REST API` остальные данные для этой записи и заполнить поля.

Как лучше решить эту проблему?

По идее подошел бы метод `get_context_data(...)`, но корректно ли его использовать без использования моделей как таковых? 
Изменил TemplateView:

```
class SomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'sometemplate.html'
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = kwargs
        context['myvar'] = 'somevalue'
        return context
```

Как мне теперь в контроллере `AngularJS` получить переменную `myvar`?

Comment: Angular, как и многие другие js-фреймворки, это прежде всего [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), а значит [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState). При таком подходе на клиенте состояние отлично сохраняется.

Comment: @romeo спасибо. Т.е., скажем, при нажатии на кнопку редактирования записи в контроллере AngularJS нужно вызвать по `ng-click` функцию, в которой выполнить `history.pushState({myvar: значение_переменной}, null, url)`, только что записать в качестве `url`? Адрес страницы с формой редактирования? И далее выполнить переход `window.location.href('адрес страницы с формой редактирования')` ? Далее я оказываюсь на странице редактирования, куда мне нужно добавить получение JSON-данных с моей переменной `myvar`, чтобы использовать в контроллере `AngularJS`?

Comment: Разбить форму на две последовательные ("шаг за шагом"), можно и без смены URL-а. Необходимо определиться должна ли ваша форма "шаг за шагом" работать без js. Существуют таже сценарии, когда пользователь решил зачем-то обновить страницу с формой (F5) или закрыл браузер (ушёл спать), т.е. необходимо ли сохранять состоние формы в такой ситуации. В Angular уже реализован специальный [контроллер для формы](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), который позволяет [валидировать форму](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Comment: В момент возникновения события `ng-click` (для формы можно использовать `ng-submit`) проверяем валидность формы `$valid` и отправляем данные. Менять или не менять при этом URL на ваше усмотрение. В Angular присутствует pushState-функциональность. Для её активации необходимо в конфиге указать  `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`, а именно: `angular.module('app', []).config(config); config.$inject = ['$locationProvider']; function config($locationProvider){         $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, rewriteLinks: false});}`

Comment: По умолчанию, если активировать данный режим, то Angular будет действовать с позиции SPA, т.е. все линки будут не кликабельны - любое изменение URL-а в таком случае будет отслеживаться [роутингом](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider). Если нам не нужно такое поведение (новомодный SPA с рендерингом на клиенте), то необходимо выставить `rewriteLinks`, как `false`. Теперь можно вручную менять URL с помощью объекта [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location), к примеру, когда наш `$http.post` успешно отработал.

Comment: В вашем случае, `$http.post` можно задействовать только на последнем шаге, хотя вполне возможно, что на первом шаге, вам будет необходимо проверить существует ли пользователь с таким email/логином на сайте. Данные же просто мержим между шагами.

Comment: @romeo на `config.$inject = ['$locationProvider'];` выдает ошибку `$locationProvider is not defined`.  Мне непринципиально, переходить фактически на другую страницу или нет, визуально форма для редактирования должна заменять страницу с набором записей, т.к. модальное окно - в данном случае не вариант. Пожалуй, легче будет это реализовать просто посредством toggle, переключаясь между основным списком и формой редактирования/добавления.

Comment: `$location` входит в `angular.js`, в отличие от, к примеру, маршрутизатора или анимации, потому ошибок быть не должно. Вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/45mrrb2s/). Загляните в консоль и убедитесь.

`просто посредством toggle` да, можно и так.

Comment: Если это админка, то можно смело использовать SPA, ибо индексация поисковивками не требуется (знаю, что google умеет прекрасно читать js, а про остальных вендоров ничего не могу сказать - требуются костыли в лице PhantomJS) и можно заставить администрацию сайта (админов, модераторов. редакторов...) не использовать IE < 9. Могу посоветовать готовую [админку](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin).

Comment: @romeo спасибо, не админка, но индексация не требуется, и будет использоваться IE >= 9. Как лучше подключить шаблон для формы, сейчас он в отдельном html файле? в основном файле через <script type="text/ng-template" ..>, наверное, получится громоздко. Update: нашел про подключение http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/AngularJS/AngularJS_Example/Template/ng_include_inline_template.htm но если html файл с формой отдельно, а не в header, как в примере, и в основном шаблоне я подключаю <div ng-include src="файл_с_формой.html"> из-за url-шаблонов на стороне сервера отдается не та страница.

Comment: Обычно, если что-то небольшое, то `<script type="text/ng-template" ..>`, а так пусть get запросом подтягивает шаблон. Отдвать его вашим django-приложением или как статику (можно в assets положить вместе с остальной статикой) решайте сами. Если как статику, то можно задействовать кеш nginx-а + отсутствие оверхеда на инициализацию django.